# Garbage collection of class instance variables in ruby

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection

If I use a method like

```
 def self.get_service_client
   return @service_client if !@service_client.nil?
   @service_client = #initialize logic
 end
```

Now `@service_client` is an instance variable of a class. How long is it in memory? Can I bank on it to not be re-initialized as long as the class is in memory (i.e like a static variable)?

Comment: How is this off-topic?! I think it is a perfectly valid question about Ruby programming.

Comment: Agreed. Re-opened, and I'll kindly request that the folks who closed it explain why. This is a fully legit question.

Answer (score 12):

Classes are instances in Ruby, too, but when you define a class the usual way, it gets assigned to a constant, and that constant is referenced by other constants, preventing its collection. So, the class will be in memory indefinitely. Since the class will remain in memory, the class instance variable will too, as the class (which is an object instance) retains a reference to its instance variables.

As an aside, the idiomatic way to do this is:

```
def self.get_service_client
  @service_client ||= initialize_service_client
end
```

Comment: About your "aside": What do you do if the initialization code is more than just one expression? Create a dedicated method?

Comment: I usually either refactor into an initialization method, or you can use `@service_client ||= begin...end`. The result of the `begin..end` block will be returned as the value of the expression.